# Returning NullReferenceException while trying to get Element by name

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I am experimenting the features of linq to xml, while trying to simulate the method `XElement.Descendants("Users")`, I have the following code; my question is why the second line

```
var usersElement = xElement.Element("Users"); // this is returning null
```

is returnning null? here's the full code wrapped in main()

```
  XElement xElement = XElement.Load("Users.xml");
        var usersElement = xElement.Element("Users"); // this is returning null
        var userElements = usersElement.Elements();
```

Here's the Users.xml:

```
<Users>
    <User name="Surender" type="Senior Developer" />
    <User name="Parvind" type="AVP" />
    <User name="Adam" type="Manager, Vice President" />
    <User name="Dongming" type="Junior Developer" />
</Users>
```

Comment: Replace: `XElement xElement = XElement.Load("Users.xml");` with `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users.xml");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `XElement.Load` it returns the root element.You are searching for your root under the root,ofcourse that's not going to work.

`xElement` is `Users`.You just need `xElement.Elements("User");` to get all `User` elements.